# Wordpress: Search Input Value returns posts from Category with that Name - Possible?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, wordpress, search

Is it possible that when a User inputs a term that matches a pre-defined term it will output all posts from that category_name? This way I can eliminate posts that are not in that category or have that search value in them.

```
Search: COMEDY matches Category: COMEDY display ALL POSTS FROM CATEGORY COMEDY
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query posts based on their category, if that's what you are asking for..
There is a clear and specific example in the documentations that explains how to query posts from a specific category - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#All_Posts_in_a_Category

anything else.. is just designing the right user interface (html/js/css)